# making the the value of a variable global in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I Have a form where you can enter data and it saves the data into the database. You can add more sets of those forms if you want to and this works by setting each input box with an id_count. I do this all via Jquery and by appending the extra forms. All these forms are under one form tag though. So it looks something like this when someone has added extra forms:

```
<form>
   <div class="fieldsetOriginal">
   </div>
   <div class="fieldset_1>
   </div>
   <div class="fieldset_2">
   </div>
</form>
```

At the moment I am getting back a set of values from the database and sending them to Jquery using PHP and I get the data back by doing this:

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data['error']) {
    alert(data['error']);
  } else {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    var x;
    var id_count = response.length;
    for (x = 0; x < response.length; ++x) {
      var my_obj = response[x];
      console.log(my_obj.name);
      console.log(my_obj.gender);
      console.log(my_obj.date);
      console.log(my_obj.relationship);
      $j('#name1').val(my_obj.name);
      alert(id_count);

      id_count++;
    }

  }
},
```

In Jquery I am also setting `var id_count = 1;` at the start of the page so the variable is global. The reason I am using `$j` is because I am using `$j = $.noConflict();` as in Magento you have to use Jquery in noConflict mode.

The problem with this though is that the value for `id_count` that I set within the ajax function is not global. This is important because if the `id_count` is one thing somewhere and another else where then I could get conflicting id's. How can I set the value which I set in my ajax function for `id_count` the main value of it for when I append the forms. How can I do this?

Sorry if this post is really long or if this is a stupid question.

Comment: and if you put this id_count value hidden in some input type="hidden"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you know, I fixed it myself!

All I did was remove the `var` from when I was declaring `id_count` within my function. I also removed the `var id_count = 1;` at the start of the document. This then solved my problem and made count_id global!

Answer (score 0):

Create a input element in your form and assign the count variable into the hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="hdnCount"/> //Element Creation


success: function(data) {
  if (data['error']) {
    alert(data['error']);
  } else {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    var x;
    var id_count = response.length;
    for (x = 0; x < response.length; ++x) {
      var my_obj = response[x];
      console.log(my_obj.name);
      console.log(my_obj.gender);
      console.log(my_obj.date);
      console.log(my_obj.relationship);
      $j('#name1').val(my_obj.name);
      alert(id_count);

      id_count++;
    }
$('input#hdnCount').val(id_count);
  }
},
```

**Another way**

```
<form>
   <div class="fieldsetOriginal" data-count=""> //add Data Attribute
   </div>
   <div class="fieldset_1>
   </div>
   <div class="fieldset_2">
   </div>
</form>

success: function(data) {
  if (data['error']) {
    alert(data['error']);
  } else {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    var x;
    var id_count = response.length;
    for (x = 0; x < response.length; ++x) {
      var my_obj = response[x];
      console.log(my_obj.name);
      console.log(my_obj.gender);
      console.log(my_obj.date);
      console.log(my_obj.relationship);
      $j('#name1').val(my_obj.name);
      alert(id_count);

      id_count++;
    }
$('.fieldsetOriginal').data('count',id_count); //Assign value in data Attr
  }
},
```

To access the data attribute value:

```
var $val= $('.fieldsetOriginal').data('count');
```